# Industrial high Load capable single Board Advise

Tags: raspberry-pi3, banana-pi

We are looking a single board computer to handle heavy cpu load (24 hour) and good connectivity. it will run for both deep-learning model's and also some sensor information. WiFi , Bluetooth , 1xLan , 4G Gsm  min 1G ram 2Gig preferred.

We came cross with :

- Raspberry pi 3 B+ Quad Core 1.4 GHz
- Banana Pi M3  Octa-core 1.8GHz CPU.
- ASUS Tinker Board QuadCore 1.8GHz

and more which we dont listed here.

Main requirements we need 24 hour heavy load (%90 all cpu's) more GHz , connectivity and sensor availibity..

Raspberry pi 3 B : when we start program it using %95 cores and heats 84-85 Celcius and sticking there. I am not sure how lon we keep that high temperature.

I need experienced advise which single board computer could be a good solution. Could be Arm / intel ?

budget range around 100 usd

Thanks A Lot.

Comment: buy the fan - temperature will go down. very simple sollution

Comment: Yes its a solution. I just want to learn experience from the field. Which configuration could be the fit 24 hour %90 cpu overload ? ir Banana Pi M3  is very good config 8core and 2G ram but read bad impressions if we utilize 8 core at %90. is the fan a real solution ?